# Get text box value on .cs page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I want to develop an application in asp.net with C#. 
In that application there are one text box and one label. 
I want the following functionality:

When I press any key in textbox then I should get this value on .cs page i.e; code behind. And from .cs page I want to add this value to the label.

The problem is that there is no keypress event for an asp textbox and if I take a html text box then I don't get its value on .cs page

How can I come out with this problem?

Comment: Do you really want to go back to the server ? Javascript would be better for such things.

Comment: I tried ontextchanged event. But it works when i press enter key in text box. I want a event which occur only by keypress.

Answer (score 0):

Because a keypress on a textbox is a client side event but you want to perform server-side processing you will need to use AJAX requests.

You may find the following useful:

[AJAX Toolit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/)

[Using Jquery to call asp.net page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net the TextBox will have TextChanged event but you will need to enable post back for the button and the event will fire when you tab out of the TextBox.
For the task you want either use javascript or add a button and when this button is do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a JavaScript-Method for this.

Your Textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox" runat="server" onkeydown="onFilterTextChanged()">
        </asp:TextBox>
```

Your JavaScript, do a TimeOut to not do this every 0,0001 secs.

```
function onFilterTextChanged() {
        if (timeoutID)
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        timeoutID = window.setTimeout(updateFilterText, 600);
    }
```

Send the Values to the CodeBehind, `text`is your TextBox-Text.

```
 function updateFilterText() {
        var text = document.getElementById("<%=textBox.ClientID %>").value;
        __doPostBack("<%=textBox.ClientID%>", "CommandArg" + text);
    }
```

You won't need to do as many PostBacks as with the native TextChanged-Event and you can simply use this e.g. for Auto-Extender-Plugins. Pack the TextBox into an UpdatePanel and you're good to go!

Unless of course you do not NEED to go back to the server, in which case just set the labeltext in `updateFilterText`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think  this is a good aproach in web app., In this way you will end with a lot of post-backs.

However, if you still want this functionality. Texbox has TextChanges event, and if you also change the textboxs's AutoPostBack property to true you will get something close, but you will still have to move a currsor.

But it is still a terible solution. Why don't you simply use a button that fires click event instead?

Alternative solution is to use Ajax or javaScript,..